# adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode behavior is different/inconsistent inside a buffer

Tags: org-mode, indentation, line-truncation

in org-mode I have adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode on.
The indentation though has a inconsistent behavior.
I have already tried to toggle visual-line-mode and word wrap but the sometimes correct and sometimes wrong indentation does not change.

[image: Inconsistent Indentation]

```
adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode is a variable defined in ‘adaptive-wrap.el’.
Its value is t
Local in buffer Bibliothek.org; global value is nil

  Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.

Documentation:
Non-nil if Adaptive-Wrap-Prefix mode is enabled.
Use the command ‘adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode’ to change this variable.

[back]
```

and here the active modes

```
Enabled minor modes: Abbrev Adaptive-Wrap-Prefix Anzu
Async-Bytecomp-Package Auto-Composition Auto-Compression
Auto-Encryption Column-Number Company Counsel-Projectile
Delete-Selection Ede Electric-Indent Electric-Pair File-Name-Shadow
Font-Lock Global-Anzu Global-Auto-Revert Global-Company Global-Ede
Global-Eldoc Global-Font-Lock Global-Git-Commit Global-Hl-Line
Global-Magit-File Global-Semantic-Decoration
Global-Semantic-Highlight-Func Global-Semantic-Idle-Completions
Global-Semantic-Idle-Local-Symbol-Highlight
Global-Semantic-Idle-Scheduler Global-Semantic-Idle-Summary
Global-Semantic-Show-Unmatched-Syntax Global-Semantic-Stickyfunc
Global-Semanticdb Ivy Line-Number Magit-Auto-Revert Mouse-Wheel
Override-Global Projectile Recentf Savehist Semantic Shell-Dirtrack
Show-Paren Size-Indication Tooltip Transient-Mark Volatile-Highlights
Which-Key Ws-Butler Yas Yas-Global

(Information about these minor modes follows the major mode info.)

Org mode defined in ‘org.el’:
Outline-based notes management and organizer, alias
"Carsten’s outline-mode for keeping track of everything."
...
```

1. How can I change my settings so that words are always truncated and indented correctly.
2. What is the cause of this problem?

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem -- did you ever find a fix?

Comment: No sorry still nothing found. 
I added `(setq org-adapt-indentation nil)` to my init.el file so that every line starts a column 0 independent of the headline level (probably just like in markdown documents)

Comment: I cannot answer question 1. (looking for a solution myself) but answer to 2. is `org-mode`: Toggling to `outline-mode` (which org-mode is based on) makes the adaptive indentation work as expected and toggling back to `org-mode` breaks it again.