# How do I get the Fringe curved arrows to show in word wrap mode?

Tags: wrapping, fringe, visual-line-mode

So I really like those curved arrows that appear in the Wrap at Window Edge option, like in this image:

[image]

But i don't like that it breaks the words at random places, in this respect I like that the option Word Wrap (or visual-line-mode) keeps the words in one piece, but as can be seen from this image bellow it does not put the curved arrow fringe thingys that I liked in Wrap at Window Edge option:

[image]

I would really like to have both options, that is a visual-line-mode with curved arrow fringes, and I know it is possible because of this image that I found in the internet (at: [adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode behavior is different/inconsistent inside a buffer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61401/adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode-behavior-is-different-inconsistent-inside-a-buffer)):

[image]

It was in a post about adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode, that I have installed but that doesn't do the curved arrow fringes thingy that I would like. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you add a link to the post where you found the last image?

Comment: @NickD at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61401/adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode-behavior-is-different-inconsistent-inside-a-buffer

Comment: Please add the link to the question, not just in a comment. Comments can be deleted at any time. Thx.